# Shipping methods are only being shown to logged in customer

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

I am using Matrix rates for weight v destination shipping but for some reason the Shipping methods do not show up in the shipping method tab for non logged in customers.

I can calculate shipping from the cart page and update totals but when I checkout I get

"Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address." when I reach the shipping method step.

If I login the message goes away!

Has anyone come across this problem before and know how to fix? Please help me out...

```
Country Region/State    City    Zip/Postal Code From    Zip/Postal Code To  Weight From Weight To   Shipping Price  Delivery Type
DEU *               0.1 5000    14.99   European delivery
ESP *               0.1 5000    14.99   European delivery
GBR *               0.1 5000    9.99    Priority processing
GBR *               0.1 5000    6.99    Standard Delivery
IRL *           BT% 0.1 5000    14.99   NI Delivery
NLD *               0.1 5000    14.99   European delivery
```

Comment: Can you test another delivery method to see if the same error occurs?

Comment: @JamesAllwood sure, I can use Free Shipping or Flat rate and it works fine...

Comment: Can you show an example from your csv? Also, do you have a weight set on your products. Matrix rates will ignore products with a weight of 0.

Comment: @JamesAllwood Trouble is, I can calculate shipping from the cart page and choose a shipping option then update totals but when I go through the checkout I get the error... see edit

Comment: Did you set persistent customer session between each stores?

Comment: Oğuz Çelikdemir persistence is enabled,

Comment: Too what address are you shipping? Might that be an issue?

Comment: @Sander Mangel UK addresses at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

- Try it with a shipping/billing address for which you have shipping
  defined above: DEU, ESP, GBR, GBR, IRL, NLD
- Try it with weight vs. destination. What's the result then?
- Can you provide us with a sample CSV?